# TOC program A that when given any program B as input can determine whether or not B produces “hello world”

Tags: turing-machines, turing-complete

“It is not possible to create a computer program A that when given any program B as input can determine whether or not B produces “hello world” as its first statement”.? need proof.

Comment: Create a TM B that outputs "hello world" if program A says that its input won't, and outputs something else if program A says that its input will.

Comment: Can you please help with some theorem?

Comment: I believe I did. What are you confused about, specifically?

Comment: he problem is that statement itself says it is not possible, we need to figure out it impossibility through some theorem

Comment: If proof by contradiction isn't the kind of proof you need, then I suggest looking at other proofs of noncomputability until you find an existing theorem that fits. I don't see the point as it's easy to demonstrate a contradiction.